# Как определить порядок прорисовки в 3D?

Tags: алгоритм, 3d

Есть набор треугольников, есть плоскость-экран, на которую они проецируются.

Как определить порядок прорисовки? Язык намеренно не указываю, можно php/delphi/actionscript, как удобнее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут много путей, и применять их надо комплексно:

1. Разбивать полигоны на более мелкие
2. Применить Z-буфер
3. Если не хочется Z-буфер, а хочется сортировать грани, то поискать более подходящие алгоритмы сортировки, например, алгоритмы [Newell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newell%27s_algorithm), [Warnock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warnock_algorithm), [BSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning)… их много.

Comment: Спасибо, пока BSP зацепил. А есть где адекватные примеры посмотреть? Пока явно не планирую делать пересечения объектов, поэтому должно же быть что-то простое)

Comment: Ну если по BSP, то вот статья неплохая: http://www.devmaster.net/articles/bsp-trees/

Comment: А правда, что направление нормали определяется тупо порядком точек?)) Я надеялся на формулу в 3 строки, а оно вон как...