# Поворот плоскости в пространстве

Tags: алгоритм, 3d

Всем привет. Это сюжетное продолжение [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/32601/3d-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8), язык также не принципиален.

Есть плоскость - проекция мира("камера"), задана точкой **`PP:{x,y,z}`** и нормалью **`PV:{x,y,z}`**. Абсолютный рандом.

Все точки(массив) - тоже **`P[N]:{x,y,z}`**. Точки заведомо принадлежат плоскости.

Ситуация: мир готов, спроецирован на камеру и ожидает показа. Нужно только выдрать с камеры 2Д-координаты относительно PP.

*Суть вопроса:* как повернуть плоскость(т.е. массив), чтобы **PP** совпала с **`{0,0,0}`**, а сама плоскость с **`OXY`**? Перетащить плоскость могу сам, квест - повернуть.

Мои мысли:

1. по матрицам поворота (некоммутативность поворота мне не обломает всю малину?)
2. как-то исходя из вектора P[N]-PP (мысль бьется в голову, но не оформляется)
3. я *уверен*, что есть простое решение)
4. Я явно где-то туплю =) Хотя есть подозрение, что это очередная глобальная проблема движков.

Если задача (вытащить координаты) проще решается другим способом, я не расстроюсь)

*ЗЫ: очень прошу, как можно меньше матриц*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем случае для камеры не хватает третьего вектора, т.к. существует бесконечное множеcтво векторов, ортогональных PV. Поэтому необходим третий вектор PU - обычно указывающий вверх относительно камеры.

Поворот мира относительно камеры (вид камеры) определяется (в правосторонней системе координат, векторах-строках) как:

```
l = PV;
r = PU x l;  // подразумевается векторное умножение
u = PU;

// так называемая LookAt матрица

             ( rx,          ux,          lx,          0 )
             ( ry,          uy,          ly,          0 )
v_view = v * ( rz,          uz,          lz,          0 )
             ( -dot(r, PP), -dot(u, PP), -dot(l, PP), 1 )
```

где вектор v - изначальное положение точки в мире, v_view - положение точки если смотреть на неё из камеры. Подразумевается, что вектора PV и PU имеют длину, равную 1.

Линейные преобразования (хотя в данном случае аффинные) удобнее всего описывать именно матрицей, т.к. это представление всегда существуют для любого такого преобразования, да и работать с ними удобно.

**UPD:** Отвечаю на комментарий о применении матриц к векторам.

Данная тема входит в курс линейной алгебры, однако можно почитать об этом отдельно: [Умножение матриц](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86).

Вектор в 3D обычно (но не всегда) это матрица-строка размера `1x4` вида `(X, Y, Z, 1)`.
Четвёртый компонент-единица необходим для однородности координат; это позволяет умножением на матрицу сдвигать вектор на некоторый другой.

Рассмотрим пример: пусть есть вектор `h = (hx, hy, hz)`. Тогда после умножения на указанную выше матрицу `A` результатом преобразования будет:

```
h_view = h * A = (h_view_x, h_view_y, h_view_z, 1)
// четвёртая компонента в данном случае не важна
// и после умножения остаётся равной 1

h_view_x = hx * rx + hy * ry + hz * rz - dot(r, PP)   // новый X
h_view_y = hx * ux + hy * uy + hz * rz - dot(u, PP)   // новый Y
h_view_z = hx * lx + hy * ly + hz * lz - dot(l, PP)   // новый Z
```

Comment: Хм, дело в том, что на плоскость камеры все точки уже перенесены, т.е. положение точки на экране известно, проблема в том, что сам экран повернут) Мб я нестандартным путем пошел, но все же... Грубо говоря, надо плоскость {PP, PV} превратить в начало координат, чтобы у всех точек было z = 0. 

*Не проецированием, естественно*

Comment: Есть некоторое недопонимание:

1. Плоскость (PP, PV) это бессмыслица, если её себе представить;

2. Повёрнут экран?

3. Преобразование плоскости в начало координат (какой плоскости?) бессмысленно, т.к. это проекция всех точек в точку (0, 0, 0). Если у всех точек плоскости z = 0, то это просто плоскость XY.

Comment: 1. повернуть точки можно в последнюю очередь, уже на плоскости, результат будет тот же. Пока для простоты этот угол опустил. Пока меняется положение, поворот вокруг OY и наклон вперед-назад. От поворота вокруг нормали изменится только поворот конечного изображения.
 2. Видимо, да) Я не камерой(точкой) "смотрю", а плоскостью.
 3. Прошу прощения, не превратить плоскость в {0,0,0}, а положить ее на OXY так, чтобы PP оказалась в {0,0,0}, а нормаль совпала с OZ. Собственно, это мой единственный вопрос, дальше я справлюсь)

Comment: Всё это (и даже больше - поворот относительно вектора "вперёд" для камеры) выполняет вышеприведённая матрица.

Comment: Ок, как с ее помощью получить 2D координаты всех точек на плоскости?

Для примера PP { 0, 10, 10 }, PV {0, -10, -10} (взгляд в начало координат). Косинусы я вытащу. Точка {0, 20, 0} должна оказаться в { 0, 10*(2/sqrt(2)) } вроде бы.